# Generalised mean inequality – intuition

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm trying to prove the inequality between generalised means
$$
\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k^p \right)^{1/p} \ge \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k^q \right)^{1/q}
$$
for $p \ge q$ and arbitrary $a_1, \ldots, a_n > 0$. I know it can be done with Jensen's inequality and I understand the reasoning in the proof, but I don't know how to do it using basic methods. I realised that I don't have the right intuition behind this inequality that doesn't rely on the function $\lambda x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}. \; x^{p/q}$ being convex.

Do you happen to have some other intuition for this problem that's more basic?

Comment: What do you mean by basic methods?

Comment: @Annika not using limits or anything more sophisticated.

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/648098/317854 or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446318/proving-the-power-mean-inequality-using-chebyshevs-sum-inequality?noredirect=1

Comment: Both discussions were of great help, thank you